# I want to validate Mobile Phone number with regexp in flutter starting 01

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to validate 11 digit Mobile Phone number with regexp in flutter starting 01

Answer (score 0):

***Try this RegExp***

```
RegExp('01[0-9]{9}').hasMatch(value)
```